# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reportingservices-2005

I have two databases DB1 (used by my application) and DB2 (third party) under same SQL Server instance

I get the following error

> SqlException ERROR: A network-related
>   or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

connecting to my database (DB1)

To fix this i used below

To assign a TCP/IP port number to the SQL Server Database Engine
In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the console pane, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, expand Protocols for , and then double-click TCP/IP.

In the TCP/IP Properties dialog box, on the IP Addresses tab, several IP addresses appear in the format IP1, IP2, up to IPAll. One of these is for the IP address of the loopback adapter, 127.0.0.1. Additional IP addresses appear for each IP Address on the computer. Right-click each address, and then click Properties to identify the IP address that you want to configure.

If the TCP Dynamic Ports dialog box contains 0, indicating the Database Engine is listening on dynamic ports, delete the 0.”

Once I deleted those zeros and put in 1433 for TCP ports on each IP address DB1 works fine, but cannot access DB2 (third party)

So basically what is the default settings 0 or 1433?

how do i get both work with default TCP/IP settings?

Thanks 
Gauls

Comment: the default port SQL Server running on is 1433. All you should be doing is enabling TCP/IP on standard port; all databases from same instance work via same port/IP

Comment: I don't have any control over DB2 it needs TCP/IP setting to be 0 (Dynamic) and ay changes to this is making DB2 unavialable to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem with SQL Server Express and resolved it by starting the SQL Server Service located within the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

It should start automatically but a manual restart will resolve the issue.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for the above issue!!